# Query for selecting rows with different values of single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to write a sql query to select rows from a table whose column in where clause will have different values based on what is being  sent.
Example: parameter sent has 3 different values for a single column name.
how do i retrieve rows which satisfy all the parameters.

Comment: Select * from TableA where Column1 IN (1,2,3) ?

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result!

Comment: @Veljko89 number of parameters (values) will change everytime .based on what is selected  from the check box.

Comment: @Veljko89 Please check the tags, that answer doesn't apply to pg.

Comment: @JakubKania true that ... my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN/ NOT IN construct...

To match all the columns that have its column value among the parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `columnName` IN ('parameter1','parameter2','parameter3');
```

To match all the columns that don't have its column value among the parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `columnName` NOT IN ('parameter1','parameter2','parameter3');
```

Comment: i have to match 40 different values.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have a large and indeterminate number of potential values.

In which case create yourself a function thus:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(max) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(5) -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(max))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(max)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

You will now be able to write a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN 
   (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplit(stringParamHere, stringSeparatorHere))
```

In this way you can pass the query a list of x values in a single parameter, with a given separator.

The above example is used for separating string values.  It is however very easy to produce a fnSplitInt that returns a table of ints, simply by changing the type of the table item and altering the line "INSERT INTO ..." to:

```
INSERT INTO @List SELECT CAST(@sItem as int)
```

The same function for postgresql looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fnsplit(
    IN stringlist character varying,
    IN delimit character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(items character varying) AS
$BODY$
declare remainderlist character varying;
declare front character varying;
declare delimitpos integer;
begin
    drop table if exists tmptbl;
    create temp table tmptbl(items character varying);
    remainderlist := $1;
    delimitpos := strpos(remainderlist, $2);
    while delimitpos > 0 loop
        front := trim(both from(left(remainderlist, delimitpos -1)));
        remainderlist := substr(remainderlist, delimitpos + 1);
        if length(front) > 0 then
            insert into tmptbl values (front);
        end if;
        delimitpos := strpos(remainderlist, $2);
    end loop;
    --insert last value
    remainderlist := trim(both from remainderlist);
    if length(remainderlist) > 0 then
        insert into tmptbl values (remainderlist);
    end if;
    return query
        select * from tmptbl;
        return;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this to match large number of values

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName IN (select 
unnest(regexp_split_to_array(comma_separated_values::text, ',')));
```

Alternately You can write a `Function` also with `comma_separated_values` as input parameter like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction(comma_separated_values Text)
  RETURNS refcursor AS

$BODY$
DECLARE
cur_data refcursor;

begin
open cur_data for
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName IN (select 
    unnest(regexp_split_to_array(comma_separated_values::text, ',')));
  return cur_data ;
end;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

> EDIT: you can create a another function with `text array` as `input`
>   parameters

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction(values Text[])
      RETURNS refcursor AS

    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    cur_data refcursor;

    begin
    open cur_data for
     SELECT * FROM table WHERE columnName IN (select unnest(values));
      return cur_data ;
    end;

    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i made it work in java with for selecting rows which satisfied my parameters and appending it to the list